# User login writing direct to database from app or from app to web interface?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, web

I have created an app for Android and iOS. I will now be implementing the create account / user login aspect of the app. I plan on using Amazon Web Services, specifically Amazon DynamoDB for my database. Amazon Web Services has an SDK for iOS and Android that allows you to read and write directly to the DynamoDB fairly easily.

My question is this: from a design point of view and in terms of efficiency, is it better to handle the user login by writing the logic in each app and then reading / writing to the DynamoDB through the SDK or is the better option to create a web interface where the app would do post requests to the web interface which would then communicate with the Amazon DynamoDB?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use a web server, for security.  Otherwise you have to put your password to access the db in your app-  and poof, there goes the security.  It would be ok to login via a web service and pass a runtime authentication token down to the app, but you don't want the app to have the login info directly.

Comment: I accepted your answer but I'm just wondering since you seem to have a lot of knowledge, why did Amazon Web Services create the ability to write directly to the Amazon DynamoDB? Thanks! http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html